# How get current timestamp in C++ since 1970?

Tags: c++, unix, timestamp

There is some way I can get current timestamp in **C++** just like JavaScript's `Date.now()`does?

**(whithout `chrono`)**

I am using `flot` JQuery Library for drawing charts, and it's default time measure is 1970's January 1, 00:00:00 UTC, so my C++ backend must suit to it.

I'm sorry if it's repeated question, but all that I found uses `chrono`, which I don't have access. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cant use `chrono` try using [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html) instead.

```
time_t result = time(NULL);
printf("%s%ju secs since the Epoch\n", asctime(localtime(&result)), (uintmax_t)result);
```

Here is a [live example.](http://ideone.com/NTWmRj)

Note that this is available on most POSIX compliant systems, but not all systems are POSIX compliant.

Comment: The `time` function (which you should have mentioned is declared in `<ctime> or `<time.h>`) exists on all conforming hosted implementations. POSIX guarantees it returns seconds since the epoch, and defines the "epoch" as  1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: I've tried it but uintmax_t was not declared in the scope. Should I replace it? If yes, by what exactly?

Comment: @LuizGuilhermeFonsecaRosa This is a cast, and it might not be necessary, it is for the printf only. unix and posix usually make time_t a signed integer.

Comment: @Ben Ok then, it worked. Altough it returned something different from JavaScript.
C++: 1467070603
JS:    1467070611310
Look the digits difference between them.

Comment: @Luiz It looks like javascript is returning `ms` since epoch not seconds. Seems likely you also ran the programs at different times which also account for the difference. If this program worked for you, feel free to mark it the correct answer. [Here](http://www.epochconverter.com/) has it at `1467070985s` which is close that returned by c++.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not guaranteed for all implementations, it's pretty common for the old C `time()` function (found in header `ctime` or `time.h`) to get a timestamp in seconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970 (and it is mandated on POSIX).

Comment: Beat me by 13 seconds :(

Comment: You should say where `time()` is declared (`<ctime>` or `<time.h>`).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Although I don't think it's worth editing just to remove it, I mostly disagree. It's one thing when you have a function like this that you're not going to run across from random Googling. Once you've given them enough information to type `man time`...well, there's room for argument that man pages are open to improvement, but this isn't the time or place to try to do so.